# how to print entire HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to print the entire element including tag name, attribute name/value pairs and innerHTML. How can I do it in JavaScript (jQuery)?

for example:

```
var elArr = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
alert(elArr[0].printEntireElement());

//expected output might be 
<link href="/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
```

Note that for link element outerHTML is not defined!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an outerHTML jQuery plugin, like [this one](http://dbj.org/dbj/?p=91), or [this one](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/).

Comment: Damn, I did it (http://dbj.org/dbj/?p=91) but it seems so inefficient ... But I can't think of anything better, still ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do outerHtml, clone it, create a new div, place the clone in the div, and grab the innerHTML of the container.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery to create a div in jquery. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getHTML= function(who){
    var txt, ax, el= document.createElement("div");
    el.appendChild(who.cloneNode(false));
    txt= el.innerHTML;      
    ax= txt.indexOf('>')+1;
    txt= txt.substring(0, ax)+who.innerHTML+ txt.substring(ax);
    el= null;
    return txt.replace(/>/g,'>\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print an entire tag from a jQuery element you could do something like this:

```
var el = $('<div id="my_div">test div 123</div>');

alert(el[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
function dump(element) {
  var a = ["Element dump:"];
  for (var k in element) {
    if (element.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      a.push(k + ": " + element[k]);
    }
  }
  a.push("HTML: " + element.innerHTML);
  alert(a.join('\n'));
}
```

Whether you want the "hasOwnProperty" test or not, I don't know.