# Java selenium grabbing entire html contents of the element

Tags: java, html, selenium

I was wondering if there was a way to get the entire html code between two tags of an element, along with the element tag then store it in a string.

Lets say I use the following to create a list of web elements, then fill the list with all the web elements.

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
//Some for loop after this to access each value
```

If I use the following to get the 3rd web element, it prints only the tags name, as it should:

```
System.out.println(element.get(3).getTagName());
```

so it prints the paragraph element "p" or "input" for example if it is the 3rd web element stored

But I was wondering if its possible to get the entire html code line for the web element and print it rather then only the tag name "p" for example?

e.g.

```
<p> some text </p>
```

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: is using selenium a requirement in this case? for instance using javascript, it coulld be easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631019/how-to-print-entire-html-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read `outerHTML` attribute to get the entire element.

```
element.getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

Or in your case:

```
System.out.println(element.get(3).getAttribute("outerHTML"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Much appreciated, this is exactly what I was looking for!