# Can I load and unload gallery with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, gallery

I'm making a portfolio site in which each project expands on click and inside there's a image gallery.

The problem I'm facing is that the site gets pretty slow once many images are loaded. Is there a way to load the content on click and once I click some other project, the previous gallery content to be completely unloaded ?

I'm not very experienced with jQuery so an example of this would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you click, create a new div, load everything you want to show inside that div and show it to the user. Have a button there to close it. Once you do, destroy the div.

To create the div read: [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

To destroy it just $('#div_id').remove();

Comment: That would mean I'd have to load every single project individually, sounds a bit messy.