# javascript: how to dynamicly generate a div in front end?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing a chat function that one user might chat with multiple ones at one time, which need generate multiple div to load the chat page. Typically, I just write div with an id there, and call it using jQuery. Now, since I don't know how many div need to be called at the same time, I can not write it in advance. Any idea? Or if you have better solution, let me know too. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should be able to dynamically insert a `div` element into your page by first selecting the parent element and using the `.append("<div>stuff</div>)`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will allow you to assign unique IDs to each chat div so you can send the chat output to the specific page elements.

```
var number_of_chat_sessions = 4; // Adjust according to your needs, or assign programmatically

for ( var i=0; i<number_of_chat_sessions; i++) {
    var chat_div = $( "<div>Initial output here</div>" ).attr( "id" , "chat_session_" + i );
    $( "#chat_container" ).append( chat_div );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery need:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.setAttribute('id', "your_current_id");
wrapper.appendChild(newDiv);
```

`wrapper` is the JavaScript object that will contain the `div`

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexBay/3pdaV/2/)

Comment: This will apply the ID "id" to every new div, which is invalid. IDs must be unique.

Comment: It was just an example and it creates only one div indeed

Comment: OP: "...need generate multiple div..."

Comment: This is the procedure to dynamically generate a new div with an id, generating more is just changing the id, like in my demo

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('body').append(
        $('<div/>', {
            id: 'element_' + i,
            html: 'item ' + i
        })
    );
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Z8Z/1/).

Comment: Based on the OP's stated goal, he will likely need to assign a unique ID to each div so chat events can be forwarded to the correct element.

Comment: @George Cummins, I have updated my answer to take into account your suggestion.