# jCarouselLite Rebinding Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I have a jCarouselLite plug in on my website. I am loading the li's from a jquery.load function.  I cycle through the carousel vertically and have a function that triggers as soon as the first item comes back around to the top.

At this point, I want to refresh the data with another ajax.load.  This is where I run into a problem.  Once that data is reloaded, the carousel stops rotating (or rather, is running in the background).

One solution I tried is to try re-instating the carousel with another:

```
$("#tableapp").jCarouselLite({})
```

line.  This seems to cause two carousels to be running at the same time.  And then a third, and 4th, and so on.

So basically I am looking for some way to clear the carousel, reload the updated data, then run it again.  Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            updateConsole()    //Gets new data
            scrollWindow()     //Starts carousell
    });

    function updateConsole() {
         $('#tableapp').load('AjaxPages/ApplicationMonitor.aspx #application');
     }

    function scrollwindow() {
       $("#tableapp").jCarouselLite({
            vertical: true,
            hoverPause: true,
            visible: 4,
            auto: 6000,
            speed: 500,
            scroll: 4,
            circular: true,
            afterEnd: function (a) { ScrollEnd(a); }
        });
    };

    function ScrollEnd(a) {
        $('#tbDebug').val($('#tbDebug').val() + '\nScroll Ends');

        if (**code that determines slide 1 is back on top**) {
            updateConsoles();
            scrollWindow(); //If this code is commented, the carousel stops cycling.
                            //If it isn't commented, two carousels start and things
                            //get buggy and eventually freezes.
        }
    }
```

I am pretty new to javascript, jquery, etc.  I also tried this on jCarousel (not lite), but I couldn't get it working with vertical scrolling. It seemed buggy.

Comment: To solve this problem, I eventually started using jCarousel rather than jCarouseLite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not-particulary thought out suggestion:

When you ScrollEnd, .remove that div.
    http://api.jquery.com/remove/
Then recreate it and dump load into it.
    [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Does that trick it into working?