# How to use Javascript to create parent and child element at the same time with variable contents

Tags: javascript, variables, element, parent-child

I have a JSON from PHP assoc array:

```
Array(
    [0] = > Array(
        [topicid] = > 17
        [entry] = > number 12 this one
        [belongdate] = > 2017 - 06 - 12
        [edittime] = > 2012 - 06 - 18 05: 22: 21
        [User_ID] = > 1
    )
    [1] = > Array(
        [topicid] = > 9
        [entry] = > yeah 11 now
        [belongdate] = > 2017 - 06 - 12
        [edittime] = > 2012 - 06 - 18 05: 22: 02
        [User_ID] = > 1
    )
)
```

I don't give you JSON straightly is because I don't know how to print JSON properly.

I need to create parent div and multiple children elements:

```
        <div name='entrydiv' class='entrydiv'>          
            <h3 name='topich3' class='topich3'>
                entryjson[i]['topicid']
            </h3>
            <p name='entryp' class='entryp'>
                entryjson[i]['entry']
            </p>
            <a name='belongdatea' class='belongdatea' style='display: none;'>
                entryjson[i]['belongdate']
            </a>
            <a name='lastedittimea' class='lastedittimea'>
                entryjson[i]['edittime']
            </a>
        </div>
```

Note the contents are variable from JSON.
I have checked out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery). But the .append method does't seem to support passing variable to the content. And the .appendTo method does not allow child element(?).
I appreciate your help very mush. Thanks.

Comment: *"But the .append method does't seem to support passing variable to the content."* What did you try exactly?

Comment: Well, I tried this (maybe I just didn't do it right) `topicid=entryjson[i]['topicid'];  $("<div name='entrydiv' class='entrydiv'><h3 name='topich3' class='topich3'> topicid</h3></div>").appendTo('#bodydiv');`

Comment: Use string concatenation. For example `var str = "<p name='entryp' class='entryp'>" + entryjson[i]['entry']" + "</p>";`

Comment: @B7ackAnge7z Woow, I works perfectly. So it was all about escaping "". Thank you soooo much.

Comment: No, it's not about escaping quotes, it's about building the string correctly. How should JavaScript know that inside your string, `topicid` is a referring to a variable (and why not e.g. `entrydiv`)? How can it know you want to substitute it with its value? It can't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example.  To create this DOM structure:

```
<div name='entrydiv' class='entrydiv'> 
    <h3 name='topich3' class='topich3'>
       entryjson[i]['topicid']
    </h3>
</div>
```

You could use this plain javascript code:

```
var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
mainDiv.name = mainDiv.className = "entrydiv";
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

var item = document.createElement("h3");
item.name = item.className = "topich3";
item.innerHTML = entryjson[i]['topicid'];
mainDiv.appendChild(item);
```

You can add code for the other parts and then add a loop to iterate through your JSON to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to create the following structure:

```
<div class="yourClassInHTML">
...
<div>
<img src="thePath"></img>
</div>
...
</div>
```

then .js code would be:

```
var element1 = document.createElement("div");
var element2 = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "thePath";
element1.appendChild(element2);
document.getElementsByClassName("yourClassInHTML")[0].appendChild(element1);
```