# jquery to add one cell without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add one cell in a section each time I click the add button. The page is updated without refreshing.
The html code is:

```
<section>
  <p class="cell">content</p>
</section>
<button type="button" id="addCell">add</button>
```

How should I implement the js?Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried JQuery .append() .html() ?
Yes, post what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, use `append()` or `after()`. In your case `append()` will work better.

```
$('#addCell').bind('click',function(){
    $('section').append('<p class="cell">content2</p>');
});
```

Unfortunately I can't show you a demo because jsFiddle is under maintenance.

Demo in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/agosap/

Comment: fiddle has been excruciatingly slow for me lately so I've switched to [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com). I like it's JS debugger thingy and live updates.

Comment: God, thanks for your comment! I've edited my answer and now it contains a dmeo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addCell").click(function() {
         $("section").append('<p class="cell">content</p>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the code as you haven't shown us what you've attempted, but I will guide you.

You want to bind a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to the button so you can do stuff when the user clicks it. You can create elements using JS [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) or [using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery). So inside the click event, create the element you want, give it whatever [attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you want, and then [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it to the parent div.