# onmouseover for the last of several generated divs will not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mouseevent, onmouseover

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function addTool(id, text, tool, pic) {
   var container = getById('infobox');
   var origimg = getById('tempimg').src;
   container.innerHTML += "<div id='" + id + "' class='toolText'>" + text + "<br><img      class='toolImg' src='img/tools/" + tool + "'></div>";
   getById(id).setAttribute('onMouseOver', "mOver('"+ id +"', '" + pic + "');");
   getById(id).setAttribute('onMouseOut', "mOut('"+ id +"', '" + origimg + "');");
   getById(id).setAttribute('href', 'javascript:mClick(id);');
}
```

Which generates several `div`s, using this code:

```
addTool("1p", "Bar", "tool1.jpg", 'img/p&g-part-2_skiss1-2.jpg');
addTool("2p", "Tube", "tool1.jpg", 'img/p&g-part-2_skiss1-2.jpg');
addTool("3p", "Rotating", "tool1.jpg", 'img/p&g-part-2_skiss1-2.jpg');
```

The mouse events work fine in all major browsers except IE. It seems that all `div`s except the last will have the mouse event in lowercase which will have the mouse event exactly as written, with upper case letters.
All mouse events will fire except for the last `div`, even if I write `onmouseover` instead of say `ONmouseOVER`, which works fine on all except the last.

Comment: Not sure of the answer to this one, although I noticed your setting your DIV id's to 1p, 2p, 3p. ID's should start with a letter not a number. For more info [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html#answer-79022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @epascarello pointed out, it seems that the `setAttribute` was the culprit, so I resolved it by setting the events in inline, such as this:

```
function addTool(id, text, tool, pic) {
    var container = getById('infobox');
    var origimg = getById('tempimg').src;
    container.innerHTML += "<div id='" + id + "' class='toolText'"  +
    "onmouseover=\"mOver('"+ id +"', '" + pic + "');\" "            +
    "onmouseout=\"mOut('"+ id +"', '" + origimg + "');\" "          +
    "onclick=\"mClick(id);\""                                       +
    ">" + text + "<br><img class='toolImg' src='img/tools/" + tool + "'></div>";
}
```

Which worked just fine in all browsers, including IE.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use setAttribute to add events. Use [attachEventListener/addEvent](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

The problem you have is adding the elements to the div. You are basically wiping it away each time when you are adding the new elements. That is bad. You should be using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) to add new content to the div.

**Basic idea:**

```
function attachEvent(elem, eventName, fn) {
    if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( 'on' + eventName, fn);
    } else {
        elem.addEventListener( eventName, fn, false );
    }
}


function addTool(text, message) {

   var container = document.getElementById('infobox');
   var newTool = document.createElement("a");
   newTool.innerHTML = text;
   newTool.href="#";
   var myClickFnc = function(e) {
       alert(message);
       return false;
   }
   attachEvent(newTool, "click", myClickFnc);
   container.appendChild(newTool);
}

addTool("cat","meow");
addTool("dog","bark");
addTool("pig","oink");
```

[running example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdfds/)

Comment: It seems you were correct in that the setAttribute was the culprit. Although I decided to declare the mouse events in inline instead of using your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you declare them inline? That is a poor choice since it is a bad practice. You could always do this too which works in all browsers. `newTool.onclick = function(){ alert("a"); };`

Answer (score -1):

You could do this part with JQuery:

```
$("#"+ id).mouseover(function() {
  mOver('"+ id +"', '" + pic + "');
});
```

You can even take this a lot further:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158203/190596