# introduce element in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a element in a form with jQuery.

To do this, I clone the element, change the attribute and insert, then use .html() to convert the jquery object to  HTML object but it doesn't work.

```
function addInput(divName){
    var selector= $('#tipoProducto').clone();
    selector.attr('name', counter );

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<li>porcentaje "
       + (counter + 1) 
       + "</li><li>\
         <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'></li>\
         <li>Ingediente Activo" 
       + (counter + 1)
       + "</li><li>"
       + selector.html()
       + "</li>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? Does something unexpected happen? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Have a look at this question, it will point you to the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: @COC611 Why would you add all that code that was not part of the original question?

Comment: @Ulises: I didn't add any code, I just formatted it so that it was readable.

Comment: If you're cloning an element with an ID, don't forget to give the clone a new, unique ID.

Comment: @COC611 you are right, sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For that, I clone the element change the attribute and insert then use
>   .html() to convert the jquery object to html object but dont work.

You don't have to do that. You can do something like this instead, more generically:

```
var div = $('<div><ul><li>X</li><li>Y</li></ul></div>');
$(div).appendTo($('#' + divName));
```

No need to use `html()`, DOM code, etc. like that. In fact, you should do it that way because jQuery's DOM manipulation shortcuts are 99.99% cross browser (maker and version) whereas standard DOM calls can be different in older versions of IE.