# Add numeric class to each dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class/id with a number each time a generate a new `div` element. Using jQuery UI dialog to add title + content for my block

Eg: 
add element function {

if there is no div = `<div id="block0">`

else = count blocks = `<div id="block[i]">`

Tried with

```
$('#' + div).prepend(function (i) {
    i = 'block' + (i + 1);
}
```

but is adding same number each time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975990/dynamically-creating-div-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Please don't do this. Incremental `id` attributes is an anti pattern. Group elements using common class names and use DOM traversal to find related elements.

Comment: @NagarajS In container I have other div's too. So not all of them are dynamically generated and not all of them save numeric class.