# document.getElementById is returning null on the button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, domdocument

I have a textarea and a button. The button submits the data to a page through AJAX through a function. When the button is clicked it calls a function that takes in 3 parameters for this question only one of them is necessary.

Let's look at the code to understand more clearly:

```
var offers = <? php echo PostOffer::GetOffers($_GET["id"]); ?> ;
for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
    var date = offers[i].Date.split(" ");
    document.write('<div class="row-fluid offer">' +
        '<div class="span2">' +
        '<img class="profile_picture" src="' + offers[i].Picture_Path + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="span10">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="username">' +
        '<p style="font-weight: bold;">' + offers[i].Name + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="content">' +
        '<p class="content">' + offers[i].Text + '</p>' +
        '<textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">' + offers[i].Text + '</textarea>' +
        '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer("<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>","' + offers[i].Offer_ID + '","' + document.getElementById("edited_content") + '");\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
        '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="date">' +
        '<p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>' + date[0] + '</p>' +
        '</div>');
    if (offers[i].Username == "<?php echo $_SESSION["
    username "]; ?>") {
        document.write('<div class="controls pull-right">' +
            '<a href="" class="no_link edit_offer">Edit</a>&nbsp;' +
            '<a href="" class="no_link" onclick="showDeleteOfferModal(' + offers[i].Offer_ID + ');">Delete</a> |&nbsp;' +
            '</div>');
    }
    document.write('</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<hr />');
}
```

The important part is:

```
...
'<div class="row-fluid">' +
    '<div class="content">' +
    '<p class="content">' + offers[i].Text + '</p>' +
    '<textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">' + offers[i].Text + '</textarea>' +
    '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer("<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>","' + offers[i].Offer_ID + '","' + document.getElementById("edited_content") + '");\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
    '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
...
```

The most important is:

```
...
'<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer("<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>","' + offers[i].Offer_ID + '","' + document.getElementById("edited_content") + '");\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
...
```

In the onclick of that button the function `document.getElementById("edited_content")` returns a null value. I've tried logging it to the console it prints null. Why is that happening?

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: That is happening because when the string is interpreted (ie. before being inserted into the DOM) the `#edited_content` does not exist.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that using `document.write` to dump a massive string into the DOM is a terrible way of doing things. You should refactor this to create actual DOM nodes, or use a templating plugin.

Comment: that's a hell of code in that onclick atribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at the point you call `document.getElementById("edited_content")`, `edited_content` does not exist.

You are creating it by appending a string, so you'd need to do something like:

```
// Add the first part
document.write('<div class="row-fluid offer">' +
        '<div class="span2">' +
        '<img class="profile_picture" src="' + offers[i].Picture_Path + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="span10">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="username">' +
        '<p style="font-weight: bold;">' + offers[i].Name + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="content">' +
        '<p class="content">' + offers[i].Text + '</p>' +
        '<textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">' + offers[i].Text + '</textarea>');
// Now we can get edited_content
document.write('<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer("<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>","' + offers[i].Offer_ID + '","' + document.getElementById("edited_content") + '");\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;');
// Write the rest of the HTML
document.write('<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="date">' +
        '<p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>' + date[0] + '</p>' +
        '</div>');
```

P.S. You tagged the question with jQuery - [there are much better ways of doing what you are trying to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery). Better still, use a [templating engine](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

Comment: Well the code I provided should work. The links I provided should explain the better ways to solve this problem. The rest you'll have to do yourself