# Add div bloc elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array of JSON object like this :

```
var array = [
{title : "TEST1", img : "http://www.myTest1.com/test1.jpg"},
{title : "TEST2", img : "http://www.myTest2.com/test2.jpg"},
{title : "TEST3", img : "http://www.myTest3.com/test3.jpg"}
]
```

I would like to create the following bloc element (using the previous array) and add this bloc into an existing `<div id="content"></div>` in my webpage :

```
<div id="line1">

        <div class="item">
            <h2 id="item_text">
                <span>TEST1</span>
            </h2>
            <div class="img-div">
                <img id="item_img" src="http://www.myTest1.com/test1.jpg" alt="" height="333px" width="500px" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <h2 id="item_text">
               <span>TEST2</span>
            </h2>
            <div class="img-div">
                 <img id="item_img" src="http://www.myTest2.com/test2.jpg" alt="" height="333px" width="500px" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <h2 id="item_text">
               <span>TEST3</span>
            </h2>
            <div class="img-div">
                <img id="item_img" src="http://www.myTest3.com/test3.jpg" alt="" height="333px" width="500px" />
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

How can i do that in `Javascript` / `JQuery` ?

Comment: What do you want ur result to be? I dont quite understand ur question.

Comment: @wawanopoulos this is a pretty basic question, tell us what you've tried and we will help you.

Comment: I would like to create dynamically the global div element 'line1' from data array and add this created element into an existing one "div id="content"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a div element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/dY9Kk/)**

Create a *model* which stores the HTML content to be populated. Iterate over the array and append it.

```
 var line = $("#line1");
 for (a in array) {
     appendModel(a);
 }

 function appendModel(num) {
     var model = '<div class="item"><h2 id="item_text"><span>' + array[num].title + 
         '</span></h2><div class="img-div"><img id="item_img" src="' + array[num].img + '
     " alt="" height="333px" width="500px" /></div></div>';
     line.append(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for?

```
var myNewDiv = $("<div></div>");

//append content to myNewD

myNewDiv.appendTo($("#content"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("line1").innerHTML += "<div id='content'>";

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
document.getElementById("line1").innerHTML += "<h1>" + array[i].title + "</h1>"
document.getElementById("line1").innerHTML += "<img src='" + array[i].img + "'>";
}

document.getElementById("line1").innerHTML += "</div>";
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/ms8zH/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ; in your array its supposed to be a ,

Use this:

```
var array = [
{title : "TEST1", img : "http://www.myTest1.com/test1.jpg"},
{title : "TEST2", img : "http://www.myTest2.com/test2.jpg"},
{title : "TEST3", img : "http://www.myTest3.com/test3.jpg"}
]
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var arrayLength = array.length;
var insertHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  insertHTML += array[i].title + array[i].img;
}

document.getElementById("youdivID").innerHTML= insertHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.each()` to create the html and `jQuery.append()` function to append it to the target div

```
var array = [
    {title : "TEST1", img : "http://www.myTest1.com/test1.jpg"},
    {title : "TEST2", img : "http://www.myTest2.com/test2.jpg"},
    {title : "TEST3", img : "http://www.myTest3.com/test3.jpg"}
];

/*
 * put your target div selector here
 * I have simply played with this page elements
 */
var newHtml = '';

    $(array).each(function(index,item){
    newHtml += '<div class="item"><h2 id="'+ item.title +'"><span>'+ item.title +'</span></h2><div class="img-div"><img id="'+ item.img +'" src="'+ item.img +'" alt="" height="333px" width="500px" /></div></div>';
});

$target = $('#question-header').append(newHtml);
```

Comment: Change your loop function parameter positions : `array.forEach(function(item,index){ }`

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var array = [
        {title : "TEST1", img : "http://www.myTest1.com/test1.jpg"},
        {title : "TEST2", img : "http://www.myTest2.com/test2.jpg"},
        {title : "TEST3", img : "http://www.myTest3.com/test3.jpg"}
        ]
        function gen(myArray){
            var html = '<div id="line1">'
            for (var i = 0, i < myArray.length; i++){
                html += '<div class="item"><h2 id="item_text"><span>'+myArray[i].title+'</span></h2><div class="img-div"><img id="item_img" src="'+myArray[i].img+'" alt="" height="333px" width="500px" /></div></div>';
            }
            html += '</div>';
            return html;
        }

        var HTML = gen(array);
        $('#content').html(HTML);
```