# jQuery create element containing child element

Tags: jquery, dom

[Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery) does a good job on describing how to create and insert an element, however, I wish to create an element with a child element such as `<li><a href="abc.html">click</a></li>`.  The href and text is susceptible to XSS, so I need take steps.  I could create the `<a>` element like:

```
var href='abc.html',text='click';
jQuery('<a/>', {
    href: href,
    text: text
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

How do I modify this to include the `</li>` element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

wrap it up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var href='abc.html',text='click';

jQuery('<a/>', {
    href: href,
    text: text
}).wrap("<li>").parent().appendTo('#mySelector');


})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eyqco

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you could append the `<li>` tag to the element with the id `mySelector`.

```
$('<li>').appendTo('#mySelector');
```

Then you append your `<a>` tag to the li element.

Comment: Thanks LiamWilson.  Thought there might be a more direct way to do so.

Comment: @user1032531 there is. check my answer ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you could wrap the li element around the <a> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, i like to do it in html directly :

```
var html = "";
html += "<li>";
html += "<a href='www.google.com' >click me</a>";
html += "</li>";

$("myselector").append(html);
```

Comment: As I indicated, the text `ckick me` is user provided.  This could result in XSS.

Comment: ..........why tho?`