# How to append a div and an image dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I wanted to ask that is there a way by which I can append a div and an image inside it using javascript?

So basiclly, images are stored in an array. **displayAllImages** function() appends the images to the div **#images** but I want that function should append a **div** and within the new div there should be the **image** may be as a **background** or an **image contained in a div**. This should repeat for all images as in **3 images should be display as 3 divs containing 3 different images/elements of the array**. Try to stick to array implementation only. Thanks!

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/

```js
    var gallery= new Array();

    gallery[0]="http://s6.tinypic.com/1zd1a47_th.jpg";
    gallery[1]="http://s6.tinypic.com/2ngh9ty_th.jpg";
    gallery[2]="http://s6.tinypic.com/29zy5qf_th.jpg";

    var x= $("#images");

    function displayAllImages() {
        var i = 0,
            len = gallery.length;        
        for (; i < gallery.length; i++) {
              
           x.append("<img class='roll' src='" + gallery[i] + "'>");
        } 
    };
     
    $(function() {
        displayAllImages();
    });
```

```css
    #container {
     width:600px;
     height:600px;
     background-color:#000;
     }

    .roll {
        margin:4px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id=images></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: When creating the code snippet, did you happen to notice that there were separate sections for JavaScript, HTML and CSS? You should put all the code in one snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
x.append("<div class='roll'><img  src='" + gallery[i] + "'></div>");
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/1/)

Comment: This seems to work but if I add a class to just created div and apply css to it (width and height) then that doesn't work. Moreover, why aren't they appearing in a row?

Comment: Because divs are block-level elements by default, if you want them to appear in a row, you need to set the inner div css to "display:inline-block;" [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/2/). I'm not sure what you mean about the classes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/6/
 check this. Why there is no effect of width and height?

Comment: actually it works! I'll figure out the rest! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you run into any other issues.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/7/ What if I need to align the image in the center of the div. Sorry, I am an amateur.

Comment: You want the entire image to be visible, or just to center what is visible?

Comment: You can make the entire image visible by setting `max-width:100%;` on the image, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/8/). Not sure what you mean. I'm off to lunch but will be back later.

Comment: @Yomesh - Horizontal center align is `text-align:center;` in CSS

Comment: @Yomesh - And if I may just give some other advice: `var i = 0;` followed by `for (; i < gallery.length; i++) {` really doesn't save that much resources or speed. I'd say just use `for (var i=0; i<gallery.length; i++) {` (but maybe that's just me)

Comment: @Yomesh & APAD1 - But what isn't just me is this: `len = gallery.length;` followed by `for (; i < gallery.length; i++) {`... You are storing the array-length into a variable, but then you go and just reference the array directly in the for-loop. You never use the `len` var.

Comment: @APAD1 - Actually I am using this as thumbnails for my slider/lightbox. So, when user hovers over any image then some event should trigger may be a caption should appear or some effect. See this : http://jsfiddle.net/yomesh/1qk3voxq/13/ Can you please suggest some effects and ways to implement them on hover. Thank you :)

Comment: @myfunkyside - yes I know. I'll delete the repeating/useless code once I am done with what I want to achieve.
text-align:center to align images in the center of div wasn't working.
Check out the latest fiddle I posted and tell me if my method of lightbox is decent or not and if you can suggest some ways to make thumbnails look better then it would be great!

Comment: @Yomesh - Oh also, this `$(function() {displayAllImages();});` is really not necessary. You can just call `displayAllImages();` directly, does not need to be wrapped in a function.

Comment: @myfunkyside if in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yomesh/1qk3voxq/15/ I delete the " len " then the pics just disappear. Any idea why?

Comment: @APAD1 if in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yomesh/1qk3voxq/15/ I delete the " len " then the pics just disappear. Any idea why

Comment: @Yomesh - Because now (if you did what I think you did) the line above that looks like this: `var i = 0,`. You need to remove that comma and close it with a `;`

Comment: @myfunkyside : Ya. I didn't notice that. Did you see the whole code? Thanks!

Comment: @Yomesh - I'm looking at your version 13 now. It's got quite a few errors. It's probably better to start a new question for your new problem. Here: **http://jsfiddle.net/1qk3voxq/18/**, I added some comments to your code to get you started.