# Recommended way to extend DOM object in AngularJS without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm using angularJS (without jQuery), lo-dash.js and coffeescript..

Below is my codes:

```
      div = document.getElementById('play')
      iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.id='iframe_played'
      iframe.width = '420'
      iframe.height = '315'
      iframe.src = './home.html#/video/'+ currentMarker.id
      iframe.frameborder = '0'
      iframe.allowfullscreen = 'true'
      iframe.webkitallowfullscreen = 'true'
      iframe.mozallowfullscreen = 'true'
      div.appendChild(iframe);
```

which looks a little clumsy.. I know it would be super easy if I could use jQuery but unfortunately I didn't import jQuery becasue AngularJS recommend not to do this..

Does anyone have suggestions about refactoring them? (The best way may be put them all in css.. But the `src` should be dynamic and `allowfullscreen` seems not supported by CSS..) Thanks!

Comment: this is cool 'pure' js code. Don't worry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: @degr thanks..but I didn't want to import jQuery library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a directive like below ( [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitthk/f00abcda/) ):-

```
    todoApp.directive('linkFrame', [function () {
    var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'A';
        directive.transclude = 'true';
        directive.scope = { ngModel: '=ngModel'};
    directive.template = '<iframe width="420" height="315" ng-src="{{ngModel}}"></iframe>';

        directive.link = function ($scope, element, attributes) {
        };
    return directive;
}]);
```

Usage is simple:-

```
<div link-frame ng-model="lnk.link"></div>
```

I think directive should be the right way to go for DOM manipulation and transcluding the child element. If you would need more control, you can take a look at [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Please mark as answer if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
function newElement(name, params){
var out = document.createElement(name);
for(var i in params){
out.setAttribute(i, params[i])
}
return out;
}
```

var div = newElement('div', {'class': 'myDiv', id: 'divId'});