# jQuery Editing innerHTML after selecting it with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I am generating rows dynamically with PHP from DB, once it compiles the initial page code looks something like this:

**Snippet**

```
<div class="options" id="options">
        <div class="left_wrap">
            <ul>
                <li class="col_id b-bottom"></li>
                <li class="hazard_header"><h3>Hazard</h3></li>
                <li class="hazard_input b-bottom"></li>
                <li class="con_header b-bottom"><h3>Controls</h3></li>
                <li class="cat_header"><h3>Consequence Category</h3></li>
                <li class="cat_options"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right_wrap">
            <h2>Inherent Risk (Assessed risk without controls)</h2>
            <ul class="fields">
                <li class="bg b-top b-right"><h3>Consequence Level</h3><br/><span class="con_level_val"></span></li>
                <li class="b-top b-right"><h3>Probability</h3><br/>Possible</li>
                <li class="bg b-top b-right"><h3>Exposure (frequency)</h3><br/></li>
```

After page load I grab contents of the wrap `options`.

**jQuery Snippet:**

```
content = $("div.options").html();
```

Which in turns stores the above code in the variable `content`. Now, my question is how can I edit contents of variable `content`. For example I need to add value to `li` with class `Col_ID` like 1,2,3,4 and same when I am deleting I need to modify the contents again.

How can I do something along the lines `content.getElement`?

Comment: What do you mean by store? Do you really need that HTML string? If you omit the `.html()` you variable will have a reference to a perfectly usable jQuery Object, which does allow methods like `.find()`, what seems to be exaclty what you want.

Comment: I find it much easier to work with JQuery Objects... As @acdcjunior mentioned, you don't need the html, you can get the whole thing as an object by `var options = $("div.options);`  Then from there, the find method to grab specific objects: `options.find("ul.fields");`  You can also create objects in JQuery rather easily.  See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158203/3033053

Comment: All I want to do is grab the contents of WRAP (id="options") modify the elements and put it back into WRAP. What this app does is sort of a excel sheet that user can add and remove rows and edit columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to work with the HTML string, here's something you can do:

```
content = $("div.options").html();
var $content = $(content);
// now $content is a jQuery object with a bunch of (detached) elements
// you can use the common functions on it without problems, such as
$content.find("li.col_id").text("Some text");

// now you need to do something with $content, or everything you did will...
// ...be lost. You cold, for instance, update the other variable back:
content = $content.html();
// content now has the updated HTML
```

Now, if you don't need the HTML string at all, then you can work directly like:

```
content = $("div.options");
content.find("li.col_id").text("Some text");
// now the DOM was already updated as you are dealing with attached elements
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, this is even better than what I was trying to do :)