# onload event in <img> tags firing prematurely in Firefox, not other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, onload

The `onload` event in inline HTML is firing prematurely in Firefox and all browsers based on its Mozilla codebase (Tor, etc.) For example:

```
<img onload="myFunction()" src="image.jpg" />
```

This calls `myFunction()` after the image is fully loaded on Chrome, Opera, IE, and Safari (not sure about the new Edge browser, though), which is the expected and documented behavior.

However, on Firefox and its relatives, the function is called ***immediately*** upon the browser reading the `<img>` tag, i.e. ***before the loading of the image is finished***. This is not the documented behavior and causes application problems.

This is confirmed and discussed in detail a few years ago here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626613

I can't find anything that solves the problem, though, and I wonder if anyone else has run into this problem and has found the solution.

Comment: For proof of this, try this: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<img onload="loadImage()" src="image01.jpg" /></a>
<img onload="loadImage()" src="image02.jpg" /></a>
<img onload="loadImage()" src="image03.jpg" /></a>

<script>
var loaded_counter = 0;
function loadImage() {
 loaded_counter++;
 alert(loaded_counter);
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be solved doing something similar than what is done here
[image.onload event and browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache)

this could be the solution you are looking for

```
var img = new Image();
$(img).on('load', function() {
  alert("image is loaded");
});
img.src = "http://url.image.jpg";

$(img).appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/GKFxP/5/

What i guess is your problem is that the onload that is associated to the img tag is the window onload method https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use an inline onloadI() operator in the <img> tag itself. See my comment above for an example of what takes place...use your own images, then run the code in Chrome, Safari, and IE, and the counter will increment from 1 to 3. In Firefox, it will decrement from 3 to 1. I've reported this to Mozilla.