# Nesting table elements using Div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to nest elements inside tables elements with a simple JavaScript/jQuery function? For example, each square has a unique ID (A1, B7, C5). Using that ID how could I place the checker image in any given tile when the tile is clicked?

[image: board]

Comment: You should provide some code you've tried.

Comment: I've really just been searching the internet for a line of code like TableDivId.add(element). I haven't written anything down because I'm just looking for an existing function that will do this. @JordanS

Comment: Your answer is: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: Great, I thought so! Could you provide an example? @Tom

Comment: `$("#A1").append($("<div></div>"));`

Comment: You might want to peruse the [jQuery Manipulation functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Comment: @Tom That worked great, thank you!

Comment: @Stryner I will take a look!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a div element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('check');
  var col = $(this).prevAll('td').length;
  var row = $(this).parent().prevAll('tr').length;
  console.log(row + ' ' + col);
});
```

```css
table tr {
  background-color: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1),
table tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: black
}
table td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
table td.check:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-image: url('https://lh4.ggpht.com/Vp9KgW5XXVC31JPh_LmB6KQDK6OK-dwawspREgTx4Jo1EshyaIU_HTB_Dw1fK57bB84=w300');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```