# append is not exist on a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code

```
for (i = 0 ; i< number ; i++){
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.append("<label for=\"timeslot\" class=\"p-label-required\">Time Slot</label>")
    iDiv.append("<label class=\"input-group p-has-icon p-custom-arrow\">")
    iDiv.append("<select id=\"timeslot\" name=\"timeslot\" required=\"required\" class=\"form-control\">")
    iDiv.append("<option class=\"p-select-default\" value=\"\">Select value</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"1\">1</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"2\">2</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"3\">3</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"4\">4</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"5\">5</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"6\">6</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"7\">7</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"8\">8</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"9\">9</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"10\">10</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"11\">11</option>")
    iDiv.append("<option value=\"12\">12</option>")
    iDiv.append("</select>")
    $("#numberOfTablesDiv").appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

i got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: iDiv.append is not a function
```

Comment: `append()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: @rnevius so? i already have jquery included

Comment: `iDiv` is not a jQuery object.

Comment: what you need is `$(iDiv).append`

Comment: But in order to use a jquery method such as .append() you have to use a jquery selector such as $(iDiv) is what @rnevius is saying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a div element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example: iDiv.appendChild();
append function is not javascript for jquery. Sorry I'm Turk not speak English

Comment: $( "#iDiv" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" ); ?

Answer (score 0):

append is not a function, there is appendChild, but it is used for appending HTML elements, so you should try iDiv.innerHTML += [thing to add].