# Creating div's and textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to create 2 div and text box in java script like that

```
<div class="a1">
 <div class="a2">
 <input type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

is it possible?

Comment: I presume, you want to create text-box and div's on click of a button?

Comment: no i just want to create that structure using javascript

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: I'm removing the `html5-canvas` tag since your question has nothing to do with html5 canvas. Google `javascript document.createElement` for more information about using javascript to create your html elements.

Comment: Have you Googled “How to create an element in JavaScript”? You could have found [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Comment: like that: jQuery("#foo").append("<div class='a1'><div class='a2'><input type='text'></div></div>");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible:

```
var div_a1 = document.createElement('div');
div_a1.className = 'a1';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div_a1);


var div_a2 = document.createElement('div');
div_a2.className = 'a2';
div_a1.appendChild(div_a2);


var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "text";
div_a2.appendChild(input);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5zr1Lget/

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate question. Please find a duplicate Q&A rather than adding a duplicate answer. Thanks!

Comment: Will do next time! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: thanks Simon it is working

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'a1');

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.setAttribute('class', 'a2');
div2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' />";

div.appendChild(div2)
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate question. Please find a duplicate Q&A rather than adding a duplicate answer. Thanks!