# Setting id from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create an HTML object with jQuery and set the id from a variable but I don't know how it could work.

This is the code:

```
countArticle=eval("Count" + x+";");
copy.css("width", "96px");
copy.find("img").css("height", "50px");
copy.append("Anzahl: <span class='count' id="countArticle" )>"+ 1
+"</span>");
copy.appendTo("#target").fadeIn();
```

Does anyone know, how this could work?

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Answer (score 2):

```
copy.append("Anzahl: <span class='count' id='" + countArticle + "'>" + 1 + "</span>");
```

To concatenate strings, you use a plus sign.

So you want this string:

```
Anzahl: <span class='count' id='
```

then the value of `countArticle`, and then this string:

```
'>
```

Put the strings in double quotes, and you get:

```
"Anzahl: <span class='count' id='" +
countArticle +
"'>"
```

(Note that I also removed a right paren that didn't seem to belong there.)

Comment: a friendly tip, you might want to provide an explanation, OP is clearly asking for one :)

Comment: @nem035, Most difficult thing to explain I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use + in your 4th line:

```
copy.append("Anzahl: <span class='count' id='" + countArticle + "' )>" + 1
        +"</span>");
```

Comment: This would miss the quotes around the id value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a concatenation?

```
copy.append("Anzahl: <span class='count' id='" + countArticle + "' )>"+ 1
    +"</span>");
```

Comment: This would miss the quotes around the id value.

Comment: Updated @smarx . Thanks for pointing out, though we seem to have similar answers anyway. Upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to [define attributes via an object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) when creating elements with jQuery.

> **jQuery( html, attributes )**
>
> **html**
> Type: htmlString
> A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g. `<div/>` or `<div></div>`).
>
> **attributes**
> Type: PlainObject
> An object of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.

```js
var $copy = jQuery('#copy'),
    countArticleID = 'countArticle',
    html = '<span />',
    attributes = {
      'id': countArticleID,
      'class': 'count',
      'text': 1
    },
    $count_element = jQuery(html, attributes);

$copy.append('Anzahl:', $count_element);
```

```css
.count {
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
#countArticle {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="copy"></div>
```

Of course, the code can be shortened if brevity is important:

```js
var countArticleID = 'countArticle';

jQuery('#copy').append('Anzahl:', jQuery('<span/>', {
  'id': countArticleID,
  'class': 'count',
  'text': 1
}));
```

```css
.count {
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
#countArticle {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="copy"></div>
```

For further reference, see [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery).