# What is the meaning for $("<div/>"); in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've seen this, most places on Jquery existing codes.

**What is the exact meaning of this..?** 
**How it's working..?**

Sample Jquery Code

```
var t=$("<div/>");
t.text("Dynamic Programming");
$("body").append(t);
```

the above code, working fine..

awaiting responses, *thanks in advance !*

Comment: Did you make a minimal effort? Did read the docs?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )

> Description: Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.
>
> > **html**
> >     Type: htmlString
> >     A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, not XML.
> >
> > **ownerDocument**
> >     Type: document
> >     A document in which the new elements will be created.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

So basically `$("<div/>")` creates a new DIV element.

`$("<div/>")` is the same as `$("<div></div>")`

Answer (score 2):

By using `$('<element>', {options})` you can create new element. E.g.

```
$('<span>', {'class': 'my-new-class', id: 'some-id', text: 'SPAN'});
```

you will get this element: `<span class="my-new-class" id="some-id">SPAN</span>`

Answer (score 1):

In this example it means you are telling jQuery to

1. create a new `<div>` element
2. set the text content of the div to "Dynamic Programming"
3. Append it to the body.

You can refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for additional examples and further explanation. For other ways of accomplishing the same thing you can check out this [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867981/200987).

Answer (score 1):

It says, I am creating a div block and add text value. That programmatic ally created div will be append to body. It is used for adding dynamic elements to dom.