# Inserting content inside a div using .append()

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to insert content into a div using a jQuery variable.

What I'm trying to get is this.

```
<div class="results">
  <div class="user-div">
     <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it is rendering as:

```
<div class="results">
  <div class="user-div"></div>'
  <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

The following appears to be the correct syntax.  It technically works if I use $('.user-div).append() but I'm trying to use a jQuery variable.

```
var $results = $('.results');
var $userDiv = $results.append('<div class="user-div"></div>')
$userDiv.append('<p>Hello world</p>');
```

In this case, the problem isn't appending a div to the DOM, but then also appending elements to that div using jQuery variables.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Comment: dustink1982   did you checked the answer?

Comment: I think in this case its slightly different as I was able to create a div, but was unable to append additional elements with a div... however it looks like there are a some answers on there that would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $results = $('.results');
var $userDiv = $('<div class="user-div"></div>').append('<p>Hello world</p>');
$results.append($userDiv);
```

You could also select child nodes using the context provided by the first selector:

```
var $results = $('.results');
$results.append( $('<div class="user-div"></div>');
var $userDiv = $('.user-div', $results); // We select children from the context provided by $results
$userDiv.append('<p>Hello world</p>');
```

Remember that `$()` (or, more specific, `jQuery()`) selects elements already in the DOM (or creates them if they don't exist). It's better to actually handle jQuery objects rather than HTML by itself. Makes it a lot more readable and easy to reference in the long term.

And at the end, I would end up doing something like this (way easier to understand):

```
var $results = $('.results');
var $userDiv = $('<div class="user-div"></div>');
var $text    = $('<p>Hello world</p>');
$userDiv.append($text);
$results.append($userDiv);
```

Comment: As a sidenote... I never **ever** use the reference provided by `append()` as an object. It would be preferrable to actually `append()` and then grab the reference with a selector `$()`. From a readability perspective of course.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  I had the feeling that I was referencing the wrong object, but wasn't sure which or why.  Handling jQuery objects vs. HTML will be a good rule of thumb.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because append doesn't return reference to the appended content. It is referring to the same object i.e. `results` after the first append, or no matter how many appends you would run. So try to use `.appendTo()`

```
var $results = $('.results');
var $userDiv = $results.append('<div class="user-div"></div>')
$( "<p>Hello world</p>" ).appendTo( ".user-div" );
```