# Adding div on the fly and then moving it inside the squares

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code where the blue color boxes on the left text go inside the squares after the button click. The way it is going to work in my actual code is that there will be a dropdown list of some items and I will get the value of the blue boxes (for eg. `H1 Text`, `H2 Text` etc) depending upon what is selected by the user from the dropdown. So basically I will be generating the divs related to blue boxes dynamically and the total number of boxes (and the value inside it) depends upon how many values are returned based on selecting an item from the dropdown list. (This part is not shown here and I've just hardcoded the blue boxes as this is not relevant to my question).

**My question is:**
If I want to create additional blue boxes on the fly, is it possible to achieve that? For example, I want to create a blue box with the value `F6 Text` as value and put it below the blue box where it says `G6 Text`, is it possible to create one? It will be an addition of a new div like this `<div data-id="13"><span data-id="13" class="words">F6 Text</span></div>` just below the `<div data-id="12"><span data-id="12" class="words">G6 Text</span></div>` inside `<div id = "phrase">`

Also, I would like to create just an empty box without any value so if I have divs up to `F6 Text` in the div, it will look like `<div data-id="14"><span data-id="12" class="words"></span></div>`.

I am wondering if I need to have a button somewhere, where I need to show a pop-up dialog asking the user what value is needed and then append the `div` to the above divs or is there a better way of handling this?

Coming back to the dropdown list explanation I mentioned in the first paragraph, I was initially thinking of having these boxes or just the text shows up in a text area separated by a comma and then the user can just hit the button and the text would move inside the squares but I can't have divs inside the text area so I think this approach won't work.

```js
$(".words").draggable({
  revert: function (event, ui) {
    var bRevertingPhrase = this.closest("#drop-em");

    if (!bRevertingPhrase.length) {
      var phraseID = $(this).data("id");
      var phraseHomeID = $(this).parent().data("id");

      //If the child and parent ids don't match, we move the child to the correct parent
      if (phraseID !== phraseHomeID) {
        var correctCell = $("#phrase").find("div[data-id='" + phraseID + "']");
        correctCell.prepend(this);
      }
    }
    return !event;
  }
});
$("#drop-em > div").droppable({
  drop: function (ev, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable)
      .detach()
      .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
      .appendTo($(this).find(".content:empty"));
    $("#move-text").addClass("disabled");
  }
});
$("#phrase > div").droppable({
  drop: function (ev, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).prependTo(this);
  }
});

const myButton = document.querySelector("#move-text");
myButton.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
    fill();
  },
  {
    once: true
  }
);

var reOrder = [];
function fill() {
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#phrase > div > span");
  var newLoc = "";

  myButton.classList.add("disabled");

  cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
    newLoc = document.querySelector(
      ".item:nth-child(" + reOrder[index] + ") .content "
    );
    newLoc.append(cell);
    newLoc.classList.add("moved");
  });
}
function reArrange() {
  var limit1 = 85;
  var limit2 = 91;

  for (let loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      reOrder.push(limit1 + i);
    }
    limit1 = limit1 - 12;
  }
  for (let loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      reOrder.push(limit2 + j);
    }
    limit2 = limit2 - 12;
  }
}
reArrange();
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  counter-reset: columnCount 1 alphaCount cellCount;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:220px;
}

.grid {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  counter-increment: columnCount;
  min-width: 0;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}
.item:nth-of-type(12n + 1) {
  counter-increment: alphaCount;
}
.item:nth-of-type(12n + 1)::before {
  content: counter(alphaCount, upper-alpha);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -1.75rem;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.item:nth-of-type(n + 13)::after {
  display: none;
}
.item::after {
  content: counter(columnCount);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: -1.75rem;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  counter-increment: cellCount;
}

.words {
  cursor: move;
  transition: padding 0.5s ease;
}
.content:has(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
  overflow: visible;
}
.ui-droppable-active .content {
  overflow: visible;
}
.words.ui-draggable-dragging {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#phrase {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  color: #fff;
  width:150px;
  overflow:auto;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin:1rem 0 .5rem;
}
#phrase > div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width:150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #007bff;
  border: 2px solid #007bff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}
#phrase > div:empty {
  background: #fff;
  border-style: dashed;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.moved {
  animation: fade 3s ease;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    background: red;
  }
}

.item .content::before {
  content: counter(cellCount);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: smaller;
  color: #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1, 2rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

#move-text.disabled{
  cursor:none;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}
#phrase:has(.ui-droppable-active){
  overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- You'd need to set up something different for touch devices though -->
<h1>Drag and drop example </h1>
<button id="move-text" type="button">Move Text Content!</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="phrase">
    <!-- remove whitespace from  inside div html and then we can use :empty in css to change background -->
    <div data-id="1"><span data-id="1" class="words">H1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="2"><span data-id="2" class="words">H2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="3"><span data-id="3" class="words">H3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="4"><span data-id="4" class="words">H4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="5"><span data-id="5" class="words">H5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="6"><span data-id="6" class="words">H6 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="7"><span data-id="7" class="words">G1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="8"><span data-id="8" class="words">G2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="9"><span data-id="9" class="words">G3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="10"><span data-id="10" class="words">G4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="11"><span data-id="11" class="words">G5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="12"><span data-id="12" class="words">G6 Text</span></div>
  </div>

  <div id="drop-em" class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div><!-- must have no spaces inside .content -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically add another `div` as shown in the example below. I have removed the grid as it is not necessary to demonstrate this. I have also reduced your HTML and JavaScript code to a minimum.

The important work is being done in the `addButton` event listener.

There are several ways to calculate the next id for the `data-id` attribute. I chose to get the number of children of the `div` with an id of "phrase" using `childElementCount` and then add `1` to it.

You should inspect the newly created blue box in dev tools to compare it with the existing blue boxes to make sure that all of the classes and data-ids have been added properly.

With a little adjustment, it should be possible to use the code in the event listener to create all of the blue boxes dynamically. Probably, this code should be extracted into a separate function.

Notice that I am calling the JQuery function `draggable()` again inside the event listener with:

```
$(".words").draggable();
```

to add all of the correct classes to the newly created blue box.

This method should give you an idea how to approach the rest of your problem. I am sure that you should be able to get the text of the blue box from an appropriate `input` element.

```js
$(".words").draggable();

const addButton = document.querySelector("#add-blue-box");

addButton.addEventListener(
  "click", () => {
    const phraseDiv = document.querySelector("#phrase");
    let nextId = phraseDiv.childElementCount + 1;
    const divElement = document.createElement("div");
    const spanElement = document.createElement("span");

    spanElement.textContent = "F6 Text";
    spanElement.setAttribute('data-id', nextId);
    spanElement.classList.add('words');

    divElement.appendChild(spanElement);
    divElement.setAttribute('data-id', nextId);

    phraseDiv.appendChild(divElement);

    $(".words").draggable();
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 220px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#phrase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem 0 .5rem;
}

#phrase>div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #007bff;
  border: 2px solid #007bff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Drag and drop example </h1>
<button id="add-blue-box" type="button">Add Blue Box</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="phrase">
    <div data-id="1"><span data-id="1" class="words">H1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="2"><span data-id="2" class="words">H2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="3"><span data-id="3" class="words">H3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="4"><span data-id="4" class="words">H4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="5"><span data-id="5" class="words">H5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="6"><span data-id="6" class="words">H6 Text</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to do this with JQuery (which is only a JavaScript library) then the following code snippet would be one solution:

```js
$(".words").draggable();

const addButton = document.querySelector("#add-blue-box");

addButton.addEventListener(
  "click", () => {
    let nextId = $("#phrase").children().length + 1;
    let text1 = "F6";
    let text2 = "Text";
    $("<div>", {
        "data-id": nextId
      })
      .append($("<span>", {
          "data-id": nextId,
          class: "words"
        })
        .text("Ln#" + text1 + " " + text2)
      ).appendTo($("#phrase"));
    $(".words").draggable();
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 220px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#phrase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem 0 .5rem;
}

#phrase>div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #007bff;
  border: 2px solid #007bff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Drag and drop example </h1>
<button id="add-blue-box" type="button">Add Blue Box</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="phrase">
    <div data-id="1"><span data-id="1" class="words">H1 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="2"><span data-id="2" class="words">H2 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="3"><span data-id="3" class="words">H3 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="4"><span data-id="4" class="words">H4 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="5"><span data-id="5" class="words">H5 Text</span></div>
    <div data-id="6"><span data-id="6" class="words">H6 Text</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This answer about [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158203/18595321) may be worth reading.

Comment: Thanks. So adding a div could be done using jQuery as well, right? Or would it miss some of the details that you mentioned?` let html =
          "<div data-id=" +
          i +
          "><span data-id=" +
          i +
          ' class="words">' +
          "Ln#" +
          text1 +
          " " +
         text2 +
          "</span></div>";
        $("#phrase").append(html);`

Comment: @Tan Well, JQuery is just a JavaScript library so there should be many ways to do what you want to do including your suggestion.