# Dynamic (AJAX) HTML creation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dynamic

I'm seeking input on this topic, as explained below.  In particular I am looking for a "best known method" or design pattern regarding how to dynamically build HTML.

This is a very common task for me:
Submit something to a server via a POST --> get a list of results back in JSON format --> take this list of 0 to n results and display them, often as a list.  This usually means building the actual HTML in Javascript (jQuery) with something like:

```
HTMLResult = "<div id=....     "
HTMLResult = HTMLResult + JSONDataElement
HTMLResult = "</div>"
...
```

Then I add each element using jQuery or bundle them up and replace the HTML of some container div.

I'm sick of doing this.  It's error prone, ugly, inefficient, etc...

I'd much rather do something more OO.
Perhaps an *Element* would be defined somehow - is it in a div, span, what does it contain... so that I can do something like this:

```
tempElement = new Element
tempElement.text = JSONData.text
ResultsList.addElement(tempElement)
```

I am seeking any input on better ways to do what I've described.  I prefer a minimal toolset: HTML, CSS, jQuery.

(Also what about building the HTML on the backend, in this case, Django)?

Comment: I would not omit `var` and semicolons in JS code. That can get you in trouble (and is bad style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning elements is supposedly quite fast, so what I sometimes do is include templates of the elements to be generated in the initial page, with `display: none`. Then, when I receive data from the server, I can

```
var newElement = $('#some-template').clone().removeAttr('id');
```

Then, it depends on how much must be replaced. Sometimes I just set the required attributes and set the text etc., sometimes I have placeholders in the template and go something like

```
newElement.html(newElement.html().supplant(paramObj));
```

where `paramObj` holds the values to replace the placeholders, and `supplant` is taken from [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html). Modifying the String prototype is not without issues, of course, but can, in this case, easily be avoided by using a function.

Comment: the `supplant` string extension is really powerful stuff :)

Comment: This is similar enough to my answer +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask the web designer to create a pretty
   dummy list if he/she hasn’t already
   created one
2. Remove all the dummy list
       elements but one
3. Hide the last
       remaining list element (e.g.
       display:none)
4. In the last remaining
       element, create placeholders for the
       variables sent by the server (e.g.
       span)
5. In your JavaScript, deep-clone the
       element, make the substitutions,
       make the element visible, and attach
       the element to the proper node

I would not generate the HTML on the server.

Comment: This is similar enough to my answer, +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you think of writing generic function with the parameters for target Dom Element and the data to be added? You can think of a generic method like:

```
function GenericAjaxResponseHandler(TargetElement, AjaxResponse)
{
    //Implemet the handler here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the easiest way to create new elements is on backend, where you have absolute control over creation in pure html.. While on client side you have to create all those elements programatically. However the biggest **downside** of this method is that you kill reusability of the JSON provider.

If you are interested in data reusability, a RESTful like system and OOP element creation, I would suggest [Dean Edward's Base JS class](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/), which **simplifies OOP in JavaScript** and may help you a lot in creating your custom *elements and builders*.

With *Base* you can create an easy class hierarchy, which makes your code readable and maintainable.

If one of your concerns is jQuery element creation **efficiency**, read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)