# Why are my particles drifting? ( aka Is Math.random() broken or is it my algorithm? )

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Using Javascript I'm crudely simulating Brownian motion of particles, but for some reason I don't understand my particles are drifting up and to the left.

The algorithm is pretty straight forward. Each particle is a `div` and I simply add or subtract a random number from each `div`'s `top` and `left` position each round.

I read up on `Math.random()` a little, and I've tried to use a function that returns a random number from `min` to `max` inclussive:

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max  
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!  
function ran(min, max)  
{  
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
}
```

Here is the function for the movement of the particles:

```
var x, y, $elie, pos, nowX, nowY, i, $that;    

function moveIt()
{
    $("div.spec").each(function(i, v) {
        x = ran(-5, 5);
        y = ran(-5, 5);
        $elie = $(v);
        pos = $elie.position();
        nowX = pos.left;
        nowY = pos.top;

          // The min and abs are to keep the particles within a box
          // The drift occurs even if I remove min and abs
        $elie.css("left", Math.min(Math.abs(nowX + x), 515));
        $elie.css("top",  Math.min(Math.abs(nowY + y), 515)); 
    });
}
```

And here is how the particles are initially set up an the `setInterval` started.

```
$(function() {
    $("body").append("<div/>").attr("id","box");
    $elie = $("<div/>").attr("class","spec");
    // Note that math random is inclussive for 0 and exclussive for Max
    for (i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        $that = $elie.clone();  
        $that.css("top", ran(0, 495));
        $that.css("left", ran(0, 495));            
        $("#box").append($that);            
    }          
    timer = setInterval(moveIt, 60);
    $("input").toggle(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        this.value = " Start ";
    }, function() {
        timer = setInterval(moveIt, 60);        
        this.value = " Stop ";            
    });        
});
```

My problem is that using the `min` and `max` from above ( `-5, 5` ), all the particles drift up and to the left very fast.

### **[jsFiddle example of drift (-5, 5)](http://jsfiddle.net/55MPu/)**

[Example of drift even with the removal of `.min()` and `.abs()`.](http://jsfiddle.net/JVWAy/)

To counteract this, I have to use a `min` and `max` of `-1, 5`.

### **[jsFiddle example of no drift (-1, 5)](http://jsfiddle.net/qpzJY/)**

Here is the CSS for the `div` all the particles are contained in:

```
#box {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:2px #000 solid;
    position: relative; }
```

Here is the default CSS for each particle:

```
div.spec {
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#00DDAA;
    position:absolute; }
```

**What is going on? Why does a min and max of `-5` and `5` cause an upward and leftward drift?**

A test of the random function `ran()` doesn't seem to show such a persistent negative drift.

### **[jsFiddle example of testing ran()](http://jsfiddle.net/4hhKp/)**

---

The `ran()` function was taken from **[the MDC Math.random() page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is to use

```
pos = $elie.position();
```

rather than

```
pos = $elie.offset();
```

This wouldn't have made a difference had they been added to parent div, but your elements aren't properly added to a parent div, they're appended directly to the document body. So your other mistake is this:

```
$("body").append("<div/>").attr("id","box");
```

If you want the div to have id of 'box', the line should read:

```
$box = $("<div/>").attr("id","box");
$("body").append($box)
```

Otherwise you're actually giving "body" the id of "box"

EDIT:

The most efficient way to append the div would be the following (as noted by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery/327065#327065)):

```
$(document.createElement('div')).appendTo('body').attr('id', 'box')
```

Comment: Thanks Herman, the speed tests for the various ways of adding elements to the DOM come from [ **this answer** ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery/327065#327065). --------------- PS: I was editing my comment and removed that piece of code by accident, and then the time for editing the comment expired.

Comment: Here's the final version of this (not so good in IE) - http://fiddle.jshell.net/PppZ3/show/light/ - I think this calls for another type of solution... looking into [ **Raphael** ](http://raphaeljs.com)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.position()`, try `.offset()` instead. Looks like [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/gxesg/).

[Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

[Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

It works this way because you're setting the absolute '`left`' and '`top`' values in **CSS**. Instead, you can use this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GtTLv/):

```
$elie.css("margin-left", nowX + x);
$elie.css("margin-top",  nowY + y);
```

Comment: `.offset()` does seem to solve the problem. My particles are contained in a parent `div`, so I thought `.position()` would work too. Why isn't it working?

Comment: It's because your css setter is setting an absolute 'left' and 'top' instead of one relative to the parent. Instead, use 'margin-left'. See my edit.

Comment: Actually, the parent `div` has a `relative` position and the particles have an `absolute` position within the parent. The problem seems to be something funky with the parent's `id`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Sounds like fixing the root issue is the best way to go here.