# How do you create an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you create it like this: `$('<div />')` or `$('<div></div>')`

Is that how you create an element? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the element whether you can omit the closing tag.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - it doesnt matter.

Comment: @Jared: No it doesn't, jQuery is quite happy with any of [`$('<div>')`, `$('<div/>')`, or `$('<div></div>')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Comment: @DanielA.White - I'm just wondering, why?

Comment: Because jquery just parses it.

Comment: @DanielA.White - mu's link explained it. That would probably be a good addition to your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to create HTML elements using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), it looks like anything matching the regular expression `/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/` will be interpreted as a "single tag" and passed directly to `document.createElement` (assuming no `context` is specified). Therefore, at least in the current implementation, there's no difference (behavior or performance) between the various formats.

Answer (score 2):

Either way works just fine. Just don't forget to insert in the dom - you can use `appendTo(selector)`.

Comment: Do you do `$('body').append('<div />');`?

Answer (score 2):

```
var $my_elem = $("<div/>").appendTo(document.body);
var $my_elem = $("<div class='abc'></div>").appendTo(document.body);
```

Then you have `$my_elem` represending the inserted element.

Comment: This is most likely what you were after, @David

Answer (score 0):

`$('YOUR SELECTOR').append('<div />');`

The `<div />` will create a `<div></div>`

You can include classes, id's and other attributes, jQuery should figure it out and rap it up.

I included use of the append function because you are probably going to want to insert it somewhere. There is a number of similar functions you could use instead.