# Create element using JavaScript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suggest a better way to do the following in jquery . also give me the native js code to do it

```
$('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="'+confirmbox.title+'"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>'+confirmbox.message+'</p></div>')
.appendTo('body');
```

Why the need. look at "Idiomatic Syntax for Creating Elements" section of this link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Comment: seeing as how you asked so nicely :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youc colud create the elements in this way:

```
var div $('<div>', { id: "dialog-confirm", title: confirmbox.title});
var p = $('<p>');
p.text(confirmbox.message);
var span = $('<span>').addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-alert').css({ float: "left", margin: "0 7px 20px 0"});
p.prepend(span);
div.append(p);
```

and then append them as needed

Comment: which is exactly the same as explained in the link @Web Developer referenced in his question.

Comment: @Juri i thought he wanted the code to do what was written in the article since his code is different from the code found in the article

Answer (score 0):

see example here

- http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/method-createelement.shtml or
- [jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)