# How do I add text box dynamically upon Checking Check Box in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am adding form controls dynamically to my form. Below is a sample snippet how I am adding the Check Box control in my View. I also need to display a text box right below the Check box once it is Checked. Then the text should disappear once the check box is Un-Checked again. Can any one provide me some pointers on how to achieve this.

```
if (Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Type.ToLower() == "singlecheckbox")
{
    <div class="large-8 columns">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => @Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Name, Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Name)
    @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Value.Options.Count; k++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Value.Options[k].Id);
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Value.Options[k].Name);
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Value.Options[k].SecondaryValue);
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Sections[i].Questions[j].Value.Options[k].PrimaryValue)
    }
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

Comment: If you want the textbox to come into the page as the checkbox is checked, you will need javascript. jQuery would make your life easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763869/append-input-text-field-with-value-of-a-div