# How to pass a select to a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have some javascript where I append an option to a select:

```
var myuniqueddl = $('#myuniqueddl');

$("<option value='0'>--- Select a value ---</option>").appendTo(myuniqueddl);
```

I'm actually trying to do this for another select as well.

I'm wondering to avoid code duplication should I be passing the ddl to a method to do this?

```
function(someType ddl)
{
   $("<option value='0'>--- Select a value ---</option>").appendTo(ddl);
}
```

Is this a bad idea to be passing a select to a method?

Any better way of doing this?

If this way is ok what type do I pass it in as?

Comment: You can pass jQuery objects around, that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, yes, it's completely valid to pass a `select` element into a function to reduce code duplication. In this case, it seems like you're worried about having to type the same function call (`appendTo`) twice, which really isn't duplication.

Secondly, you cannot specify *any* type for a JavaScript function parameter. Variables in JavaScript are [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Dynamic). You simply specify the variable name:

```
function myFunction(ddl) {
  $("<option value='0'>--- Select a value ---</option>").appendTo(ddl);
}
```

Comment: Javascript _variables_ don't have types.

Comment: @TheZ. This is so untrue! js is a dynamic type language, but it has type all right!

Comment: @gdoron Values have type, variables do not. `typeof(x)` is telling you the type of the object stored in the variable `x`, *not* the type of the variable `x`.

Comment: Exactly. There is an important distinction between *variable* and *value*. Observe: `var x = 5; console.log(typeof x); x = 'whee!'; console.log(typeof x);` <-- same **variable**, different **value**, different types. The type, then, is a property of the value and not of the variable.

Comment: Semantics in computers are pretty important. Your statement was incorrect.

Comment: @gdoron As others have said, _values_ have type whereas _variables_ do not. I was in no way saying that JS itself doesn't have types. C, C++, Java and a host of other languages on the other hand have _variable types_ which determines what the variable can actually hold/reference.

Comment: @AnonyMouse -- please see my comments about not using jQuery+strings to create DOM elements! :)

Answer (score 3):

> If this way is ok what type do I pass it in as?

It should be jQuery element similar to:

```
var myuniqueddl = $('#myuniqueddl');
```

**Example:**

```
function addOption(el)
{
   $("<option value='0'>--- Select a value ---</option>").appendTo(el);
}

var myuniqueddl = $('#myuniqueddl');
var myuniqueddl2 = $('#myuniqueddl2');

addOption(myuniqueddl);
addOption(myuniqueddl2);
```

Or directly:

```
addOption($('#myuniqueddl'));
addOption($('#myuniqueddl2'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript functions do not use type hinting, so your function signature:

```
function(someType ddl)
```

.. is not valid.

Further, I suggest making your function a little more flexible, and to eliminate the creating of DOM elements by passing strings to jQuery ([not efficient, see this benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent/268520#268520)):

```
var addOption = function(sel, text, value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined')
        value = text;
   sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option(text, value);
}
// usage: addOption($('#myuniqueddl'), '--- Select a value ---');
//    or: addOption($('#myuniqueddl'), '--- Select a value ---', 0);
```

**Documentation**

- Functions on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions
- StackOverflow Q/A on creating elements with jQuery - [What is the most efficient way to create HTML elements using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: I would say go one step further and on top of having your generic function, add one that uses your generic and adds the standard "Select a Value" option so that the text you use is consistent throughout and you don't have to keep typing it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this, but let me give you a valid example, as your code has some syntax errors.

```
function(ddl)
{
   $("<option value='0'>--- Select a value ---</option>").appendTo(ddl);
}
```

> If this way is ok what type do I pass it in as?

Javascript doesn't use types the same way c# or java do.  Just pass a variable, similar to the code above.