# creating an element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

So, I know how to create an element in jQuery in various ways. But I've never come across this before today:

```
    var myspacer = $('<div />', {
        "id": "nav-spacer",
        "height": mynav.outerHeight()
    });
```

Later on in the code, this variable is added to the DOM with jQuery's .before() method. Can somebody explain what's going on here? What kind of object is being created? How does jQuery know how to turn this into an HTML element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the `$( html, props )` syntax of the [`jQuery()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) - it is explained quite clearly in [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/):

> `html` A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g. `<div/>` or `<div></div>`).
>
> `props` An map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.

If the function determines that the first parameter is a string that looks like an html snippet it creates a new element (or elements) from that snippet. If you pass a map in the second parameter it creates the specified attributes on the newly created element.

The new element is not automatically added to the document, but you seem to already have seen that since you mention the `.before()` code that *does* add it.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that part of the API right before I came back here to check. Answer accepted (as soon as the time limit goes away)

Comment: Note that `$( html, props )` **only** applies to html that matches `(/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/).` It doesn't apply to `<div asd></div>` (Which is a single, standalone, html element -the docs are misleading?), so `$('<div asd></div>', {text: "hello"})` will not work (As in, the `text` is not applied). Anything that regex matches will be created using `document.createElement` and the `props` will work on that.

Answer (score 3):

According to jQuery `$( html, properties)` syntax, above code creating a `div` with `id="nav-spacer"` and `height` supplied by `mynav.outerHeight()` method without any content as jQuery object but not added to DOM.

In `$( html, properties)`, `html` is string and `properties` is collection of attributes/event and so on.

An alternative approach may be:

```
var myspacer = $('<div id="nav-spacer" height="'+ mynav.outerHeight() +'"></div>');
```

But your one is more readable and efficient.

Using **[`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before)** method `myspacer` is added to DOM just before the selector passed within `.before()` as param. Example:

```
myspacer.before('div.hello');
```

Will add `myspacer` before the `div` with `class=hello` like:

```
<div id="nav-spacer" height="some_value"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery creates a new element if you pass in HTML like `$('<div/>')` because it's smart. :P It recognizes that the string is HTML (rather than a selector) and treats it differently. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

The new element is created but *not* added to the DOM until you add it yourself, eg. with `appendTo()`.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2): *"To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag."*

**Edit:** I stand corrected, you *can* write `$('<div/>')` *without* an explicit closing tag. This works as long as the HTML doesn't contain nested elements (of course). See the other examples from the docs:

```
// With nested elements and closing tags - HTML must be well formed
$("<div><p>Hello</p></div>").appendTo("body");

// Without closing tag - HTML is still well formed
$("<div/>", {
  "class": "test",
  text: "Click me!",
  click: function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("test");
  }
}).appendTo("body");
```

Similar questions:

- [jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)
- [Creating a div element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)
- [What is the most efficient way to create HTML elements using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: @zerkms: You may not need to, but the docs say you should to ensure compatibility.

Comment: @Scotty: oh, right, didn't know that and haven't experienced any issues with that

Comment: Yeah I wondered about that weird closing on the div. Not my code.

Comment: @ahren: The OP doesn't need to know the internals of jQuery ("what kind of object" it is). I don't believe that's what he was actually asking.

Comment: "How does jQuery know how to turn this into an HTML element?" - answering this with "because it's smart" isn't answering anything. Also, I do believe he was referring to the `props` object being passed through with the html snippet, rather than the html snippet itself.

Comment: This is wrong. `<div></div>` and `<div>` and `<div/>` etc are all **exactly** equal to jQuery. They all trigger `document.createElement` from a custom regex jQuery is using (`/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/`). It has nothing to do with the browser, anything you make that regex succesfully capture will be `.createElement`'d. Your quote is referring to stuff created with `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

This should give you the explanation you're looking for =D.

To summarize, it's a quick JQuery on-the-fly element creation method.