# Will it work in every browser even though <div /> is not a valid HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is `$("<div />").appendTo($mySelector)` safe to use? Will it work in every browser even though  is not a valid HTML element?

I'm asking because it's really easier to use than `$("<div><div />")`

Comment: No, if only because `appentTo` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you look at the source this case is even optimized.

```
/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/
  <div      / >               // your case
```

This regexp will match if there is or is not a `/`, and it is not included in a group. The only grouped expression is the actual tag name (`div`), which is used.

If you look more closesly you can see that the following are all handled the very same way:

```
<div>
<div />
<div></div>
<div /></div>
```

Comment: "div" would be very handy if it was supported

Comment: @André Pena: Do you mean `$("div")`? That will select div elements on the page, not create one.

Answer (score 0):

It will work correctly. `jQuery` handles the translation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but why not use `$(document.createElement('div'));` it is faster than using the jquery to create the element. It will work without running a regex and requiring translation by jquery.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/327065/897794) for a test of using different methods for element creation

Comment: jQuery isn't used becuse it's faster, it's used because it's easier.

Comment: ..and you can chain statements

Comment: you can chain statements off after the inital `document.createElement` thats why its wrapped inside of the `$()` tag. The initial creation is really expensive and using this method is loads faster especially when used inside of loops