# Wrapping some part of html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've something like:

```
<div class="the_notice">
    <span class="time"> | 3:48pm</span>
    To <strong>2013-03-16_10-56-33</strong> By <strong>XYX</strong>
</div>
```

In a result I want something like:

```
<div class="the_notice">
    <span class="time"> | 3:48pm</span>
    <div class="wrap">
      To <strong>2013-03-16_10-56-33</strong> By <strong>XYX</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery? Please help me on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if the contents will always be the same, you can do something like

```
$('.the_notice').contents().slice(2).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ysq48/

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/64DBd/3/)

```
   var temp = $('.time');
   $('.time').remove();
   $(".the_notice").contents().wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />');
   $(".the_notice").prepend(temp);
```

Comment: That doesn't work, you are removing `.time` and wrapping every single child.

Answer (score 0):

read this link it may help you :[What is the Most effcient way to create html elements using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)

My Answer is the answer well be like this :

```
var myTimeIsHere = //calculate your time here;
var x = //calculate x here.;
var y = //calculate y here.;

var newHTML = "<span class='time'>" |+ myTimeIsHere+"</span>"+
              "<div class='wrap'>To <strong> "+x+" </strong>"+
              "by "+y+"</div>";
$(".the_notice").html(newHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

With one line (or 3 for clarity):

```
$('.the_notice')
     .wrapInner($('<div class="wrap">'))
     .prepend($('.the_notice .time').detach());
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj4KA/)