# whats quicker - cloning or creating the element with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my app run as fast as possible.

At the moment, when it runs a search, it builds the results by creating each element dynamically, like:

(outside each loop)

```
var theList = [];
```

(inside each loop):

```
var titleH3 = $('<h3>').append(result.title),
    jobResult = $('<div>').addClass('job-result').attr({
                        'id': result.id,
                        'data-jobno': jobNo,
                    });
//a bunch of other info also created here (about 6 elements total)

jobResult.append(titleH3);
theList.push(jobResult);
```

then again outside loop:

```
$('#load-more').before(theList)
```

my question is, would it be quicker to have a div already in the html and clone it each time and change the info (title etc)?

Comment: The difference is minuscule. The bottleneck is not there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery follow the link to the benchmark if you are interested. It showed that using `$(document.createElement('div'))` was quite a bit faster than `$('<div>')` at the very least

Comment: Thanks! didn't even know about that method