# How can I set the 'size' attribute for the element <input> using an attribute object?

Tags: jquery

I am a jQuery beginner and have come across one of the methods to create a new element on the page. I am able to create the element fine. However, one of the attributes (size) defaults to 20 even though I clearly state that it should be bigger. Is this a jQuery bug, or am I missing something? The other attributes in the attribute object (type, autofocus) work fine.

The code I am using is this:

```
$('<input>', {
  'type' : 'text',
  'size' : 50,
  'autofocus' : 'true'
});
```

I do not have any CSS file.

When I use the attr() method, I am able to set the size. But I want to know that I am not the only one who is unable to set the size attribute for the  element using an attribute object. I am using jQuery 1.9.1.

Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: +1, interesting question, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.prop()` function:

```
$('<input>', {
  'type' : 'text',
  'autofocus' : 'true'
}).prop('size','50');
```

Or this syntax:

```
$('<input>', {
   'type': 'text',
    prop: {
        size: "50"
    },
   'autofocus': 'true'
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nkj72/1/)**

Here's the [old bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12429) when it was discovered and the explanation as to why they didn't re-enable the old functionality.

Comment: Nice find with the bug report. +1

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can use "Size" with capital S:

```
$('<input>', {
  'type' : 'text',
  'Size' : 50,
  'autofocus' : 'true'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9Hct/

Comment: I like the heck, +1 :-)

Comment: Yes it works and checked it first then `+1`ed you, `HTML` attributes are not case sensitive.

Comment: I'd think this works in jQuery because different casing is working around jQuery explicitly forbidding setting of "size" attribute (as far as jQuery is concerned it's just some custom attribute) and it works in HTML because case, as @RecoveringSince2003 pointed out, doesn't matter in HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I don't know *why* this is happening and can only assume that this is a jQuery bug as you assume.

You're already aware of using `attr()` to set the size, but for reference you can call that straight after creating the element (prior to adding it to the page or affecting it in any other way):

```
$('<input>', {
  'type' : 'text',
  'autofocus' : 'true'
}).attr('size', 50);
```

Another approach would be to simply add the attributes within the selector:

```
$('<input type="text" autofocus="true" size="50">');
```

[**JSFiddle demo of both in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/hCuj2/).