# Convert &eacute; to its orignal form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this French string:

```
Veuillez indiquer vos sp&eacute;cialit&eacute;s
```

I want it like this in my JS Alert:

```
Veuillez indiquer vos spécialités
```

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    alert('Veuillez indiquer vos sp&eacute;cialit&eacute;s');
});
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/M6rLL/

Comment: alert('Veuillez indiquer vos sp\351cialit\351s');

Comment: [PHPJS's `html_entity_decode`](http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var frenchy = 'Veuillez indiquer vos sp&eacute;cialit&eacute;s';
    alert(  $('<div />').html( frenchy ).text() );

    // If performance is an issue, you can change the dom creation of the div:
    // alert( $(document.createElement('div')).html( frenchy ).text() );
});
```

And the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PT7Je/). And [this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/327068/2519416) why the latter is faster :)

Comment: @CodeHunter update to what? It does exactly what you needed, no?

Comment: @Dark: The moment he posted the reply, the fiddle wasnt in my asnwer yet. I was working on that edit when he commented

Comment: thx , it works with me using :  var newString  = $('<div />').html( string ).text()