# Select the option dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing a dynamic HTML for Select Option like below:

```
item += "<td class='ddl' style='width:40%;'>";
item += "<select>"
item += " <option id='list' name='selector' value=" + select + ">" + select + "</option>";
for (var l = 0; l < array.length; l++) {
    item += " <option class='ddl' value=" + array[l] + ">" + array[l] + "</option>";
}
item += "</select>";
if ("One"!= '') {
    $('#list').val("One");                      
}
item += "</td>";
```

The above code creates a dynamic HTML like below:

```
<select disabled="">
<option select="" value="Please" name="selector" id="list">Please Select</option>
<option value="One" class="ddl">One</option> 
<option value="Two" class="ddl">Two</option>
</select>
```

I want to set the value of the Select to **"One"** dynamically.

**NOTE:** The code is not inside document.ready, as I cant keep the code inside ready().
Might be I am assigning the value to the Select before it is revdered on the page. Please suggest me.

Comment: What is: `if ("One"!= '') {` ?

Comment: @Felix An always `true` expression. :-)

Comment: OP: You need to append the "item" to the page - before trying to select option

Comment: And even if your `if` wasn’t nonsense – `list` is the id of your first `option` element, so `$('#list').val("One")` would only set the value of that option element.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the javaScript to select the value after the dropdown(select) is added to the page. For example if the html is

```
<div id="myContainer" />
```

Then the javascript should be like

```
var item = "";
//Insert your code to create item
item +="<select id='mySelect'>";
item +='<option select="" value="Please" name="selector" id="list">Please   Select</option>';
item +='<option value="One" class="ddl">One</option> ';
item +='<option value="Two" class="ddl">Two</option>';
item +='</select>';

$('#myContainer').append(item); //Add to html

//Now the id "mySelect" is available
$('#mySelect').val('One')
```

I've added a jsFiddle to demonstrate this at http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/n9vCb/

Comment: @Jean-Paul. Can you provide specifics of what did not work. Also please refer the jsFiddle.

Comment: That is because I added "disabled" to the select. I did this because the html in original post had disabled added.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I'll remove my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a selected attribute on the corresponding option tag as you create the select dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery` then why don't you utilize the library for creating the `select`, for example, using something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PZTs5/2/)):

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
var select = $('<select/>', {id:'list', name:'selector'});
$.each(numbers, function(key, value) {
    var text = value[0].toUpperCase() + value.substr(1);
    var option = $("<option/>", { class:'ddl', value: value, text: text });
    select.append(option);
});
select.val('two').appendTo('body');
```

I've appended the `select` into `body` but you may append it into a `td` and you can achieve it, give it a try, create the `td` same way and insert the `select` in the `td` and then insert the `td` in the table. Also you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery/19364869#19364869).