# How to populate selectbox using jquery forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is how do i populate my Birthday selectbox with data using jquery only? Is it possible to do it? Sorry but I'm just new to this...can anyone give me an example or something?

code:

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <div class="btn-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Birthday</span>
        <select name="month" class="btn btn-default" id="bmonth" data-container="body" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!" >
            <option>Month</option>
        </select>
        <select name="day" class="btn btn-default" id="bday" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!" >
            <option>Day</option>
        </select>
        <select name="year" class="btn btn-default" id="byear" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!" >
            <option>Year</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything thus far?  If so can we see your code?  If not have you tried googling `jquery add html tags` or something of that sort?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's more of a dynamic option that will change the maximum year for you every year.  I set the minimum year to 1900, but you can change this if you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm"><select id="month"></select><select id="day"></select><select id="year"></select></form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var month = [], day = [], year = [];
                for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                    month.push(i);
                }
                for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
                    day.push(i);
                }
                for (var i = 1900; i <= (new Date().getFullYear()); i++) {
                    year.push(i);
                }
                $.each(day, function (index, d) {
                    $("#day").append("<option>" + d + "</option>");
                });
                $.each(month, function (index, m) {
                    $("#month").append("<option>" + m + "</option>");
                });
                $.each(year, function (index, y) {
                    $("#year").append("<option>" + y + "</option>");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CfLKV/

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/5rQ6h/)

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

$(months).each(function(index,value){
   var curHtml = $('#bmonth').html();
   curHtml += '<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>';
   $('#bmonth').html(curHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9JLKd/1/)):

**HTML**

```
<select id='year'>
    <option>Year</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
var years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014];
$.each(years, function(k, v){
    var option = $('<option/>', {'value':v, 'text':v});
    $('#year').append(option);
});
```

You got the idea, try the rest by yourself.

Comment: I've never seen that style of creating DOM objects before, but it's very clean; well done.

Comment: You may like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery/19364869#19364869) @user3507600.

Comment: Thank you; that is very informative and descriptive.  That should help clean up some of my code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following code and create your own

```
<select name="month" id="bmonth">
    <option>Month</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var months = [
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
        'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
        'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        $("#bmonth").append(GetOption(months[i], months[i]));
    }
});

function GetOption(text, value) {
    return "<option value = '" + value + "'>" + text + "</option>";
}
```

#### **Demo**