# jquery append a class without html markup rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is there a cleaner way to append a class after a selector with out the html markup div ?

```
$('#apple').append($('<div></div>').addClass('icon-spinner')); 
//something else other than '<div></div>' ???
```

Most of the example that I found has some sort of html markup but i believe there are cleaner ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method to create a div element (performance and syntax):

```
var div = $(document.createElement('div'));
div.addClass('icon-spinner');
$('#apple').append(div);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y68L3/2/

---

References:

- [What is the most efficient way to create HTML elements using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)
- Benchmark: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement

Comment: and append the class... ?