# Why won't the newly created input tags stay on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create new input tags based on the number the user enters. My code will create the correct amount of tags, but they get removed almost immediately. Why?

```
<form>
 <input type='text' id='input' />
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="box">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').click(function() {
  var x = $('#input').val(); 
  for(var i=0 ; i < x; i++) {
        $('<input type="text" /><br>').prependTo('#box');
    };
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `they get removed almost immediately`? Does the page reload? or they just simply disappear?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364869/741747), you'll be able to create inputs using `jQuery` very efficiently :-)

Comment: Why would you use a submit button for adding elements in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl, Actually `<button>Submit</button>` is not a type of `submit`, just a button, but probably the form is submitting it but not in every brwuser, still confused tho :-)

Comment: @Alpha yes it is, if type not defined , default is submit for `<button>` and it will trigger form

Answer (score 0):

call `preventDefault` on the event to stop the `button` action from firing

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var x = $('#input').val(); 
   for(var i=0 ; i < x; i++) {
      $('<input type="text" /><br>').prependTo('#box');
   };
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mf7psgw/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your existing button to an input with an id and use the id in the JS. Your problem is the form is being submitted when you click button.

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/65gLvfdx/

```
<input type="button" id="update" value="Submit" />
```