# Show tables faster using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have thousands of records in Database and I'm giving user interface with just one Textbox where he will be putting date and records will be searched on basis of Date put in textbox. Now searching logic will be like this, ajax call will go to servlet and there all records will be fetched by firing query to database and will be put in Map and send Map back to ajax with JSON format.

Ajax will iterate over the records with each function and will match the records with date equality.Those who are Matched will be shown using .html(header+data)

Now How this whole process can be made faster or is there any another way of showing the tables with thousand records in faster way at just click of the button.I need help on this.Sorry for the BIG question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to create HTML elements using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: Have you considered using a jquery plugin with custom search filters like [jQuery Datatable plugin](https://datatables.net/) with ajax-json based source data? You can use paging like options to show only 10-50records at a time.

Comment: @Lucky No i have not use that plugin i will give it a try now..Thanks for suggestion and your valuable time..