# Create html tags with dynamic tag name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create html tags in my function like this:

```
function createHtmlTag(tagName) {
    var newHtmlTag = $(tagName);
    return newHtmlTag;
}
```

But when I call `createHtmlTag('div')` in my page this function return all my page `div` tags. I know `$(tagName)` causes this result, but I need to this method. I can solve this issue by these methods:

```
function createHtmlTagSecond(tagName) {
    var newHtmlTag = $('<' + tagName + '></' + tagName + '>');
    return newHtmlTag;
}
```

**Using JavaScript**

```
function createHtmlTagByJavaScript(tagName) {
    var newHtmlTag = document.createElement(tagName);
    return newHtmlTag;
}
```

**My question**

Is there a better way to use `jQuery` without adding additional marks like (`'<'`)?

Thanks advance.

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent) is contentful about what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that I don't need to add an extra mark (combine `createHtmlTagByJavaScript` and `createHtmlTag`).

```
function creatHtmlTag(tagName) {
    var newHtmlTag = $(document.createElement(tagName));
    return newHtmlTag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid `<` or `>` if you want to use jQuery, but you can trim it down to `var newHtmlTag = $('<' + tagName + '>');`

Moreover, according to [What is the most efficient way to create HTML elements using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1) you'd be better off using the vanilla JS approach as far as performance goes.

Comment: Thanks for response. I found simple solution for this. I had forgotten that way.