# Create html elements instead of selecting them jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create an HTML document using jquery. This is the following code I want to create

```
<html charset=\'utf-8\'>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td> sample text -1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td> sample text -2</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to create this and append it to a file. I don't want to create this using string appending. But instead it is better creating jquery elements. Tried the following:

```
var obj = $( 'html' );
console.log(obj.html());
```

Executing above code is printing the content inside html tag of present html file instead of creating a new html tag. So, is there any way to create an object of above code and stringify it? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery

Comment: You can only have one `<html>` tag on the page at any given time. Though if you want to insert elements to the page, simply use `insertNode()`.

Comment: Instead of string appending though, why not just use a string template?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals   String templates can go multiline without appending, and you can inject varaibles into them with ${variable}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html = $("<html>")
var head = $("<head>");
var body = $("<body>");

html.append(head);
html.append(body);

console.log(html.prop('outerHTML'));
```

Comment: doing the above thing is selecting the existing elements instead of creating new elements

Comment: @rammanoj did you try it?  the < > should create a new element

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't observe the tags. Worked fine with tags. Thankyou