# jquery html() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box created by jquery like so:

```
val input = $('<input class="pick_date" ... />')
```

but the .html() method on input does not return the string entered inside the $.  does anyone know why?

edit:
Ah, I understand the problem.  Is there a way to get the html representation of the entire input box and not just the entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are passing `<input />` which is a self-closing tag.

If you were passing `<input>Html here</input>` (which is valid XML but not HTML to my knowledge), you could retrieve the "**Html here**" part with the .html() function like so:

```
var input = $('<input class="pick_date">Html here</input>');
alert(input.html());
```

**In addition to your edited question:**

```
$('<input />').outerHtml();
```

this should work.. :)

**with this ofcourse ([source](http://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-outerhtml/tree/master)):**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
        return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone()).html();
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Isn't outerHtml a plugin (or IE only)?  It's not part of jquery.

Comment: true, i forgot to paste the code which makes it a jQuery plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are looking for append():

```
$("div#form").append('<input class="pick_date" ... />');
```

Comment: Might want to additionally read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Just had to deal with this problem.

If you are using ASP.NET, it could be because ASP.NET changes the id names, if you add "runat="server".

So instead of doing this:

```
<td id="mytd" runat="server"></td>
$('#mytd').html()
```

Try doing this:

```
<td id="mytd" class="myclass" runat="server"></td>
$('.myclass').html()
```