# How do I display new line in .text() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, newline

I have the following code:

```
var stringDisplay = "Hello\nWorld";
$("#meaning").text(stringDisplay);
```

It is displaying `\n` instead of a newline.

The output is showing up as `Hello\nWorld`.

I used `<br>` tag also in place of `\n`, but it's still not working.

Comment: var stringDisplay = "Hello<br />World"; $("#meaning").html(stringDisplay);

Answer (score 30):

You will have to use both `.html()` and replace the newline:

```
var escaped = $('<div>').text(stringDisplay).text();
$('#meaning').html(escaped.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
```

An alternative would be to style the element:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: This answer is not complete.  You must set the text first, to properly escape any HTML that is in the text.  Only then can you do your line replacement (assuming the new line is still there).

Comment: $('#meaning').html(escaped.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')); worked.. thanks a lot

Comment: adding style white-space: pre-wrap; works best for me.

Comment: Escaping doesn't work at all. https://jsfiddle.net/h27vxenm/

Answer (score 10):

How about this

```
$('meaning').html('line1<br>line2');
```

Comment: Would be painful if line1 or line2 is user input