# Output line breaks or new lines with json_encode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am new to JSON format so please forgive my lack of knowledge. But somehow, I need to add some line breaks to my json_encode array so that it will parse with multiple lines. I've searched and searched but nothing fits my situation.

It's outputted as:

```
Following formats accepted: www.website.com website.com website.net/something
```

But I'm looking to output the data like this:

```
Website needs to be in the following formats:  
www.website.com  
website.com  
website.net/something
```

I've tried:

```
echo json_encode( 
    array( 'status' => 'failed',
           'message' => "Website needs to be in the following formats:\n
            www.website.com\n
            website.com\n
            website.net/something"
    ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But Javascript is parsing it as a literal string so the newlines are ignored and outputted. Can I send the data from PHP to javascript using straight JSON format or do I have to use an array?

I've also tried using `<br />`.

**EDIT :**
I am outputting the following way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/forms/content_process.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: $(".content_cat").serialize(),
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.status == "failed") {
            $(".content_status").css( "background-color", "red" );
            $(".content_status").text(response.message).slideDown("normal");
        } else {
            $(".content_status").css( "background-color", "green" );
            $(".content_status").text("Your category was submitted!").slideDown("normal");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Apart from the invalid double escaping, you are already embedding  newlines by wrapping the string into multiple lines. Rather look at the outputted JSON and its use, and elaborate how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois - I've tried \n and \\n

Comment: Try combining options `json_encode($your_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Comment: How are you trying to output the message? If it's being inserted into the DOM, most elements will condense whitespace, including line-breaks, to just a space. `<pre>` and others styled with [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) being the typical exceptions.

Comment: Replace \\n with <br />, since <br /> is the new line in (X)HTML.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois - I have tried that as well.

Comment: @EternalHour Then show us how you're trying to output it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `\n` to insert newline character into the string. don't add a real newline as well.

```
echo json_encode( 
    array( 'status' => 'failed',
           'message' => "Website needs to be in the following\nformats:\nwww.website.com\nwebsite.com\nwebsite.net/something"
    ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

than on the client side before inserting it into your dom, you will need to replace the newlines with `<br />` or use `white-space: pre`. alternatively you could surround each line with paragraph `<p></p>` tags. to do so have a look here: [jQuery text() and newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines).

Comment: You nailed it @dreamlab. I would have never figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Looking back at this question, it became painfully obvious to me how simple the solution was. The reason I had such a difficulty, was because I needed to use `html` format.

Of course it wasn't honoring `<br />`, I was formatting it as text! This was the simplest way to do it for my situation.

```
array( 'status' => 'failed',
       'message' => "Website needs to be in the following formats:<br />
        www.website.com<br />
        website.com<br />
        website.net/something"
), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$(".content_status").html(response.message).slideDown("normal");
```