# Inserting new line characters into a div using $('#dividname').text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have appended a `<div>` to the body of my page using

```
$('body').append('<div id="itemInfo"><h2>TEST</h2></div>');
```

This `<div>` is hidden in my css. I am then altering the text within the `<div>` using a function as follows.

```
    function appendMessage(messagestring) {
    $('#itemInfo h2').text(messagestring);
    $('#itemInfo').fadeIn();
    $('#itemInfo').fadeOut(3000);   
}
```

This is declared using the following.

```
appendMessage("Something. ");
```

The problem is, I cannot seem to get `<br />` or `/n` characters to work within the message. How do I use new line characters within the `.text()` function?

Comment: Try wrapping the messages that you append to the div in <p> elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try use the html() function:

```
$('#itemInfo h2').html(messagestring);
```

Comment: Yeah that's it, thanks. I'll accept in a few mins (need to wait apparently)