# How to include linebreak in inserted text

Tags: javascript, php

I was just wondering how could I insert a line break in this particular code situation. I'm displaying it via jQuery's `.text()` method. I would like for there to be a line break between the message and name.

```
var textarray = [
    "\"Message\" Name",
];
```

I've tried `"\"Message\" \n Name"`, but with no success

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wa4mej2m/1/

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, but it is a php file inserted under <script type='text/javascript'> if that helps.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. But I included a jsfiddle if seeing the full code helps answer your question http://jsfiddle.net/wa4mej2m/1/

Comment: Okay thank you I will add that to the post now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery text() and newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're display the text via jQuery's `.text()`. Nothing you put in the string will cause a line break in the output, since newlines are just whitespace within HTML elements -- they're not going to be interpreted specially.

If you were to use `.html()` instead, and include a `<br />` tag in the midst of your string, things would go better:

```
var textarray = [
  "\"Message\"<br /> Name",
];

// later ...

$(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast');
```

Fixed example:

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
  });

  var textarray = [
    "\"Example\" <br> Name"
  ];
  var firstTime = true;

  function RndText() {
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
    if (firstTime) {
      $('#random_text').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeOut('fast');
      });
      firstTime = false;
    }
    $('#random_text').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast');
    });
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
  }

  $(function() {
    // Call the random function when the DOM is ready:
    RndText();
  });
  var inter = setInterval(function() {
    RndText();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 200s infinite;
  animation: pulse 15s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  3% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  30% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  60% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  90% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  100% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  3% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  30% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  60% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  90% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }

  100% {
    background: #FBFFF7
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

#random_text {
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: -moz-center;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="random_text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so if I understand correctly, I just have to add $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast'); underneath var textarray = [
  "\"Message\"<br /> Name",
];  ?

Comment: No. You replace the `$(this).text(...)` stuff in your example with `$(this).html(...)`. See the code snippet included here, which is just your jsFiddle with that change already made.

Answer (score 2):

To have a line break, if you're rendering the string in HTML, you need to add a `<br>`:

```
"\"Message\"<br>Name"
```

If you're not rendering HTML, it's `\n`:

```
"\"Message\"\nName"
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can accomplish line break with `<br>`

```
var textarray = [
    "Message <br> Name"
];
```