# javascript display multi-line text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to display a multi-lined text but it always apears as one line.

For example:

```
var text ="line 1. \n line 2. \n line 3."
```

It it supposed to be displayed like :

```
line 1.

line 2.

line 3.
```

but instead I end up with

```
line 1. line 2. line 3.
```

in a rendered html page.

I tryed jquery text and html methods but not working.

Even through angularjs, it is always the same.

```
$('#element').text(text);

$('#element').html(text);

or

<div>{{ text  }}</div>
```

Isn't there a way to get what I'm expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)

Comment: try to use var text ="line 1. <br /> line 2. <br /> line 3." and: $('#element').text(text);

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines

Comment: @bradley546994 That wont work. They would need to use `.html()` in that case.

Comment: ahh right :) $('#element').html(text);

Comment: If you want to keep your formatting and indentation along with line break, wrap the *html* content into a **pre** tag, and apply that html to DOM usin *.html(...)*

Comment: Thanks for advices. The .html() method made it but the element must be <pre> tag and not a <div>. But I still have the angularjs's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like

```
<div class="angular-with-newlines">
    {{ text  }}
</div>
```

css

```
/* in the css file or in a style block */
.angular-with-newlines {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

This will use newlines and whitespace as given, but also break content at the content boundaries. More information about the white-space property can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

If you want to break on newlines, but also collapse multiple spaces or white space preceeding the text (very similar to the original browser behaviour), you can use:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Using the css white-space property worked. Thank You.

Comment: This is a pretty clear duplicate. You should have flagged to close instead. Additionally, you should avoid gender specific words, as it could have been a female who downvoted your post.

Comment: @FrankerZ Sorry about gender specific word and being an newbie here just saw the question and started answering it, from next time I will for sure see if question is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

**May be, this is what you want...**

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<p id="text2"></p>
<button onclick="multi_line_textarea()">on textarea</button>
<button onclick="multi_line_para()">on paragraph</button>


   <script>
            function multi_line_textarea(){
                var text = "line 1. \nline 2. \nline 3.";
                var el = document.getElementById('text');
                el.innerHTML = text;
            }
            function multi_line_para(){
                var text2 = "line 1. <br/>line 2. <br/>line 3.";
                var el2 = document.getElementById('text2');
                el2.innerHTML = text2;
            }
   </script>
```

Here's a jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/p984fd1m/2/

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.
`<p style="white-space: pre-line;">{{ text }}</p>`