# How do I capture newlines with .text() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm writing a markdown editor and have an input contenteditable item, which renders formatted markdown onto another div.

```
<div name = "post" id = "input" class = "w-100" contenteditable></div>
```

```
<div id = "display" class = "col-md-6"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var md = window.markdownit()

$("#input").on("input", target =>{
    $("#display").html(md.render($("#input").text()))
})
```

How do I get `.text()` to capture newlines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery text() and newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535888/jquery-text-and-newlines)

Comment: @LightningMcQueen No. ```.text()``` doesn't capture newlines. I finally settled with vanilla JS and innerText. The suggested question deals with text editing. My question is about text capturing.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). tHis will help us to replace issues easily and give you solutions quickly.

Comment: It's not so much about *capturing* newlines as then outputting them - `.html(...text with newlines...)` will then render without the newlines.   The linked question above helps you handle that.

Comment: *I finally settled with vanilla JS and innerText.* - so you have a solution?  Please add an answer (or close your question).